# Не изменяется размер кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно изменить размер кнопок и текстового поля в зависимости от размера экрана

```
    var Width:Int=LLDate.getWidth()
    val btn1=findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button
    val btn2=findViewById<View>(R.id.button2) as Button
    val Num=findViewById<View>(R.id.tvNum) as TextView
    btn1.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams((Width/3.2).toInt(), gvDates!!.height))
    btn2.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams((Width/3.2).toInt(), gvDates!!.height))
    Width-=(btn1.getWidth()*2)
    Num.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams((Width/5.3).toInt(),gvDates!!.height))
```

Я выполняю этот код в пошаговом режиме, и после выполнения

```
btn1.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams((Width/3.2).toInt(), gvDates!!.height))
```

Ширина кнопки не меняется она так и остаётся 170, а должна быть 250
[image: размер]

И из за этого все другие размеры неправильные.
В чём может быть проблема?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="120" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:background="#ffffff">
            <Spinner
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerGroups"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog">
            </Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:background="#ffffff">
            <Spinner
                    style="@style/spinner_style"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSubjects"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" >
            </Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LLDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                    style="@style/button_style"
                    android:text="@string/app_button_back"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onClickBack"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tvNum"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/grid_date"/>
            <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gvDate"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:numColumns="1"
                    android:verticalSpacing="0sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
            </GridView>
            <Button
                    style="@style/button_style"
                    android:text="@string/app_button_next"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onClickNext"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LLHead"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="end|bottom">
            <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tlHead"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать например invalidate() у вью или у родительской ViewGroup requestLayout(). Просто изменение параметров не приводит к вызову onLayout.

Дополню еще ответ, ширина вью изменяется только непосредственно после фазы layout. Собственно если посмотрите исходники getWidth() у View - увидите что он возвращает просто mRight - mLeft, которые устанавливаются в методе layout который вызывается в процессе отрисовки view: measure-layout-draw. Если хотите как то посчитать размеры вьюшек - то смотрите в сторону getMeasuredWidth(), чтобы она вернула правильные значения - нужно вызвать для вью метод measure, в который передать ограничения по ширине/высоте для вью пропущенные через MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(...).
Если хотите чтобы вью изменилась - то вызовите как я писал ранее у родительской ViewGroup requestLayout().

Хочу предупредить что в чем то могу ошибаться так как пишу по памяти.